# GeneXus GXFlow's flow that generate multiple instances

Tags: workflow, business-process-management, genexus

I'm developing a workflow with GeneXus GXFlow.
It's a purchase request that needs multiple approval. I don't know how many, it depends by the type of products. The request is approved only when all the products are approved.
I think that the only way to do that is a process instance that generates multiple process instances of a child workflow.
Is it possibile? Where I can find an example?

Answer (score 1):

Creating multiple process instances might be a solution but there is a more efficient way to do it with multi-instance tasks.
Check out the documentation for the *Loop Type* property to see how to configure it:
https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?11898,Loop+type+property